# Changing Jquery variables

Tags: variables, jquery

I have some jquery that inputs text into a database and then clears the textarea.  However the textarea is not being cleared.  Below is the code indicating which line doenst work.  When i replace this line with alert(commentbox) I get the value of the comment box so i know that the variable is working.  I just don't know how to clear the variable.

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function () {
$('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');


$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var commentbox = $(this).children('.commentBox').val();

    $.ajax({
        "url": $form.attr("action"),
        "data": $form.serialize(),
        "type": $form.attr("method"),
        success: function () {
           $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
            commentbox = "";  //this line doesnt work

        }
    });
});
});
```

I should also mention that when i replace the bad line with $('.commentBox').val(''); the values clear.  the problem is that it clears all the textareas, not just the one that i use .children() to find.

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var commentboxElem = $(this).children('.commentBox');
```

and in your success:

```
commentboxElem.val('');
```

Comment: you are right! i will accept your answer when it lets me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $form = $(this);
 var commentboxObj = $(this).children('.commentBox');
 var commentBoxVal=commentboxObj.val();

$.ajax({
        "url": $form.attr("action"),
        "data": $form.serialize(),
        "type": $form.attr("method"),
        success: function () {
           $('.commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');
            commentboxObj.val("");  //this will work

        }
    });
```

with `commentbox=""`, you were trying to update the content of a javascript variable, not the actual textbox.

Comment: i should have mentioned that i tried that line already and it doenst work. I would have thought the same.

Comment: .commentBox is a textarea.  commentbox is a javascript variable with the value of .commentBox